# When should __method__ be called directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

When should a `__dunder__` method be called directly?  For example, instead of

```
a + b
```

one could write

```
a.__add__(b)
```

but is that a good idea?

Comment: I personally can only think of inheritance aspects: `BaseClassOfA.__add__(a,b)` or something like this.

Comment: When the use of `__method__` expresses more clear intent than the alternative

Comment: When you want to bypass the inverse being called.

Comment: You might use dunder methods if you need to supply a function to something. Ex. `reduce(int.__mul__, range(1, 10), 1)` if you wanted a makeshift factorial function.

Comment: @Kelvin The `operator` module is probably more appropriate in that case. `reduce(operator.mul, range(1,10), 1)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: How often does one want to bypass the inverse being called?  And would one do it outside of class inheritence code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no, it’s not a good idea. The operators are there for a reason after all, so when using the operator is possible, use it.

There are a few things where calling the special methods directly is useful. The most common thing would be when subclassing. So when you override a special method and you want to call the super’s method too, you will have to use the name directly.

Apart from that, having actual methods allows you to keep a reference to it, i.e. `x = a.__add__`. So when you would need something like that, you can use it. Granted, for the base operators it’s not that useful either, as we have the `operator` module which gives us binary functions for the operators already.

But there might be some edge cases. In general though: If you don’t explicitely *need* the method, use the operator. It’s a lot clearer.

Martijn Pieters mentioned another use case in the comments, which is avoiding calls to the inverse operator. As you may know, an expression `a + b` will first try to call `a.__add__(b)`. If that returns the special value `NotImplemented` though, or in other words if the operator is not implemented by the type of `a`, then Python will try to call `b.__radd__(a)` instead (if `b` is of a different type). So in cases where you want to avoid this behavior, you could call `a.__add__(b)` directly—at which point you would get a `NotImplemented` value though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In Python 3, `__radd__` isn’t called when `a` and `b` are of the same type. And no, I cannot confirm that `__radd__` is called first there either.

Comment: Hrm, I cannot get that to work on 2.7 either; memory misfire then. The subclass reverse op trumping the forward operator hook is [documented in the datamodel documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) (see the note block). It only works if the subclass `.__radd__` is not inherited.

Comment: Ah, I see there that the inverse is indeed only used if the types *differ*.

Answer (score 1):

> Is `a.__add__(b)` a good idea?

Is it easier to read? Probably not. So, generally not a good idea.

One situation where it is necessary, though, is when you're writing a subclass and need to call the a method on the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There are a few use-cases I can think of:

- Chaining to a superclass implementation:

  ```
  def __init__(self, ...):
      super().__init__(self, ...)
  ```
- Calling superclass implementations to avoid an overridden method:

  ```
  def __getattribute__(self, ...):
      ...
  def foo(self, ...):
      x = super().__getattribute__(self, 'bar')
  ```
- Calling a dunder method when operators are unavailable:

  ```
  for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
      ...
  ```
- Currying operators:

  ```
  mulByTen = (10).__mul__
  ```

In general, though, the operators are simpler and clearer.

Comment: I don't think you should pass in self explicitly when calling the dunder method